# Adding a relationship in Cypher if no existing relation regardless the relationship properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to add a new relationship between two nodes if the relation doesn't exist.

```
Match (p:Partner)-[:HAS_COMMISSIONS]->(cc:CommissionConfig),
  (gc:GroupConfig)
   where gc.server="3"
    Merge(cc)-[:BELONGS_TO_ADA_GROUP{aa:100,bb:200}]->(gc)
```

this query works and adds a relationship if it's not existing but if i re-run the same query and changed these values `BELONGS_TO_ADA_GROUP{aa:300,bb:300}` a new relationship will be added because of a new properties to the relationship.
Can we force MERGE to ignore properties? I need to add a relation only if no relation, regardless of relation values.

Comment: can you try this?
Match (p:Partner)-[:HAS_COMMISSIONS]->(cc:CommissionConfig),
  (gc:GroupConfig)
   where gc.server="3"
    Merge(cc)-[r:BELONGS_TO_ADA_GROUP]->(gc)
with r
set r.aa=100, r.bb=200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the properties only if the merge results in a create:

```
MATCH (p:Partner)-[:HAS_COMMISSIONS]->(cc:CommissionConfig),
      (gc:GroupConfig)
WHERE gc.server = '3'
MERGE(cc)-[r:BELONGS_TO_ADA_GROUP]->(gc)
  ON CREATE SET r.aa=100, r.bb=200
```